# Non-real numbers in system of equations

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus, systems-of-equations

Given $a^2+b^2=1$,
$c^2+d^2=1$,
$ac+bd=0$

To prove

$a^2+c^2=1$,$b^2+d^2=1$,$ab+cd=0$

Now this can be easily done by trigonometric substitution if it was given that $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers.

I have a solution using matrix which I think is valid even if the given numbers are non real.
https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h475289p2661966

I am curious to know if there other ways to it Algebraical or with any other method.

Comment: You want even more solutions? There are already several solutions given there. The matrix solution by Ghoshadi is very nice, (and not restricted to real numbers), and you have mentioned it.

Comment: What makes a trigonometric substitution invalid for complex numbers? The complex trigonometric functions would still have to satisfy these equations.

Comment: I don't think the rest are correct as they assumed a,b,c,d are real, I want solution which would work even for non real numbers

Comment: @peteforeman I don't know much about complex trigonometric functions, could you elaborate on how a+ib can be expressed as sin(z)  and what will be z in this case

Comment: @Raunitsingh You would just use a branch of the complex arcsine function to provide such $z$.$$z=\arcsin{(a+bi)}$$

Comment: In your first line, I presumed you meant $ac+bd=0$. @Raunitsingh

Comment: @DietrichBurde: The "solution" by Ghoshadi in the OP's link assumes that $(AA^T)^T=A^TA$. But $(AA^T)^T=AA^T$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This says that
$$\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}$$
implies
$$\pmatrix{a&c\\b&d}\pmatrix{a&b\\c&d}=\pmatrix{1&0\\0&1}.$$
This follows from the fact that (over any commutative ring) any square matrix
with a left inverse has a right inverse (necessarily the same as the left inverse).

But if you want an "equational" proof avoiding concepts from linear algebra
observe that
$$a^2+c^2=1+a^2c^2-(1-a^2)(1-c^2)=a+a^2c^2-b^2d^2=1+(ac+bd)(ac-bd)=1$$
and similarly for $b^2+d^2=1$. Also
$$ab+cd=ab(c^2+d^2)+(a^2+b^2)cd=(ac+bd)(ad+bc)=0.$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint:

From [the linked question](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h475289p2661966) with $ac+bd=0$

Use [Brahmagupta-Fibonacci Identity](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Brahmagupta-Fibonacci_Identity#Theorem)

$$(ac+bd)^2+(ad-bc)^2=(a^2+b^2)(c^2+d^2)$$

In our case $$ad-bc=\pm1\ \ \ \ (1) $$

Already we have $$ac+bd=0\ \ \ \ (2) $$

Solve for $a,b$  in terms of $c,d$ using $c^2+d^2=1$